# Make a custom lookup for Material-Table column filtering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I want to make a custom lookup in material-table to look like this multiple select seen in the [material-ui documentation](https://v4.mui.com/components/selects/#multiple-select) [image]

The problem is that a Select field with the `multiple` prop requires that value is an array, which I cant get to work.  Is there any way to get around this?

This code is just for a basic Select field under the `filterComponent`.

```
filterComponent: ({ columnDef, onFilterChanged }) => (
    <Select
        value={[columnDef.tableData.filterValue]}
        variant={"standard"}
        multiple
        onChange={(e) => {
            onFilterChanged(columnDef.tableData.id, e.target.value);
        }}
    >
        <MenuItem key={"New"} value={"New"}>
            New
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem key={"In Progress"} value={"In Progress"}>
            In Progress
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem key={"Completed"} value={"Completed"}>
            Completed
        </MenuItem>
    </Select>
),
```